# What is the "$" character when used in gulpfile.js?

Tags: gulp

Sometimes I see the "$" character used in gulpfile.js scripts.

I am used to the "$" character used as an abbreviation for jQuery. Does it have a different meaning in gulpfile.js?

Here is a short example of the "$" character in use.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
       $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
```

What does $ mean and how is it used?

Comment: I don't see the question itself as being particularly useful. In your example, you are simply defining a variable, so... clearly `$` is the variable's name. Could just have well been `blah = requ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has no special meaning. It is just a variable name. (Historically it was one that was reserved for machine generated code so it wouldn't accidently overwrite any manually written variables, but prototype.js and jQuery ignored that, became popular, and the spec writers dropped the guideline as it had been well and truly broken.)

`require('gulp-load-plugins')` calls a function with an argument which returns a value. That value is a function.  Putting `()` after it calls (with no arguments) that second function. The return value of that is assigned to the variable called `$`.

A simpler demo case would be:

```js
var $ = "some string";

document.body.innerHTML = $;
```

Comment: OK. Is there a purpose for using it? I would have figured for code readability and share ability the use of named variables would be better practice.

Comment: @Rubix_Revenge — It's short.